# How to set image width and height automatically in a waterfall view?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I am building a waterfall view just like pinterest. Now I have to explicitly set the width and height of each image, is there a way to let image autofill the suitable width and height?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it. I have already fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`UIImageView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), under `initWithImage:`

> This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view by default.

If your image is in a `UIImage` object, calling `initWithImage:` should create a `UIImageView` with an appropriately sized frame for your picture.

```
// Get your UIImage from somewhere
UIImage *myImage = ...

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```